# WCF DataContract Enum error message back to the user

Tags: c#, wcf, enums

I have a WCF Web Service, and I have decorated the data member enum data type with this (using DataAnnotations)..

```
[EnumDataType(typeof(MaritalStatuses), ErrorMessage = "MaritalStatus - must be a valid value.")]
public MaritalStatuses MaritalStatus { get; set; }
```

Which comes from an internal enum.

```
public enum MaritalStatuses
{
    Married = 1,
    Cohabiting = 2,
    Single = 3,
    Divorced = 4,
    Seperated = 5,
    Widowed = 6
}
```

I am trying to give as much information back to the requestor as possible but the problem is that if the request contains anything other than one of the text options above (Married, Divorced etc) the service throws an error which does not give any indication what is wrong. Like this..

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
         <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:InternalServiceFault</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en-GB">The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the &lt;serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.</faultstring>
      </s:Fault>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Data Annotations for all other data types work as expected and give the appropriate message back to the caller, but with enum I can't get a nice message back. It's almost like the DataContract will not allow it to get as far as the DataAnnotation check (or the DataAnnotation check is wrong).

Here is part of the class where the Enum resides

```
[DataContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(DrivingLicenceTypes))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(MaritalStatuses))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(ResidentialStatuses))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(EmploymentStatuses))]
public class Applicant
{
    [DataMember]
    [EnumDataType(typeof(MaritalStatuses), ErrorMessage = "MaritalStatus - must be a valid value.")]
    [Required]
    public MaritalStatuses MaritalStatus { get; set; }
```

Comment: _"if the request contains anything other than one of the text options"_ Can you show us this request please, your question is vague right now. How do you call/invoke this service. Can you please describe it all and include the source.

Comment: Your MaritalStatuses enum must be decorated with DataContrat and its members (Married, Cohabiting, etc) must be decorated with EnumMember.

Comment: Are you exposing these types directly in the service operations?

Comment: Thanks for your replies.. gidgeon, my problem is that the service is not just called from a WCF Client, but from PHP (SOAP) and Java. It's difficult to know how their requests are put together, but the culprit of the "unable to service the request.." error are the Enums.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.. gidgeon, my problem is that the service is not just called from a WCF Client, but from PHP (SOAP) and Java. It's difficult to know how their requests are put together, but the culprit of the "unable to service the request.." error are the Enums.
I have now changed my documentation to show only the enum element, rather than the value. However when I built it I thought that when I used an Enum it would accept the value like this "<MaritalStatus>1</MaritalStatus>", rather than this "<MaritalStatus>Married</MaritalStatus>".

Comment: If you try and put anything other than "<MaritalStatus>Married</MaritalStatus>" it throws the error I described.

Comment: I suspect that Ricardo is on the right track.. and I should have originally decorated the Enums with EnumMember as he is pointing out, but now this service is out there I am reluctant to change it.